# Left Join not work with GROUP BY and WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

Please consider this script:

```
declare @Tbl1 Table
(
    [Value]   int,
    [Text]    NVarchar(50)
)

declare @Tbl2 Table
(
    id        int identity(1,1),
    [Value]   int,
    [Year]    int
)

insert into @Tbl1
Values (1, N'Val 1'), (2, N'Val 2'), (3, N'Val 3'), (4, N'Val 4')

insert into @Tbl2 Values 
    (1, 2011), 
    (1, 2011),
    (2, 2010),
    (3, 2011),
    (2, 2011),
    (1, 2010),
    (1, 2014),
    (2, 2014),
    (3, 2015),
    (1, 2015),
    (2, 2015),
    (4, 2015),
    (1, 2011)
```

I ran this select on these tables:

```
select t1.[Text], count(*) as 'Count'
from @Tbl1 t1 left join @Tbl2 t2 on t1.Value = t2.[Value] 
where t2.Year=2011
group by t1.[Text]
order by 1
```

I expected to see all the values ​​in the first table in the output, but I got this result:

```
Text        Count
-------------------
Val 1         3
Val 2         1
Val 3         1
```

Why I don't see `Val 4` in output?

I changed the select this way:

```
select t1.[Text], count(*)
from @Tbl1 t1 left join @Tbl2 t2 on t1.Value = t2.[Value] and t2.Year=2011
group by t1.[Text]
order by 1
```

and I got this result:

```
Text         Count
-------------------
Val 1          3
Val 2          1
Val 3          1
Val 4          1
```

The wonder is I hadn't `Val 4` in `Year` 2011 !?!?

Thanks

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222295/discussion-on-question-by-arian-left-join-not-work-with-group-by-and-where-claus).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wish other SQL Server questions were so clear - a minimal script that reproduces the problem, something others can easily copy and test, and a clear question, with an easy answer.

A `LEFT JOIN` would return a `NULL` for t2.Year which will be eliminated by the `WHERE t2.Year=2011` clause.

If you executed just :

```
select t1.[Text],t2.Year
from @Tbl1 t1 left join @Tbl2 t2 
    on t1.Value = t2.[Value] and t2.Year=2011
```

You'd get

```
Text    Year
Val 1   2011
Val 1   2011
Val 1   2011
Val 2   2011
Val 3   2011
Val 4   NULL
```

and `WHERE t2.Year=2011` would eliminate the last row.

To avoid this, you can either allow null years, or move filtering somewhere else.

**IS NULL**

You could allow nulls in the WHERE clause with `IS NULL`:

```
select t1.[Text],count(*)
from @Tbl1 t1 left join @Tbl2 t2 
    on t1.Value = t2.[Value] and t2.Year=2011
where t2.Year=2011 or t2.year is null
group by t1.[Text]
order by t1.Text
```

This produces:

```
Text    Count
Val 1   3
Val 2   1
Val 3   1
Val 4   1
```

That's what the desired response is but I'm not sure `val 4` should produce `1` as there are no related rows. `Count(id)` would produce 0:

```
Text    Count
Val 1   3
Val 2   1
Val 3   1
Val 4   0
```

**Subquery**

You can use a subquery that produces *only* the T2 appropriate T2 rows, eg:

```
select t1.[Text], count(*) as 'Count'
from @Tbl1 t1 left join 
    ( select Value 
      from @Tbl2 
      where Year=2011) t2 
    on t1.Value = t2.[Value] 
group by t1.[Text]
order by t1.Text
```

**Cross Apply**

Another option would be to use `CROSS APPLY` to calculate the count of matching T2 rows:

```
select t1.[Text], Cnt as Count
from @Tbl1 t1 cross apply 
    ( select count(*) as Cnt
      from @Tbl2 t2
      where Year=2011 and t1.Value = t2.[Value] ) t2
order by t1.text
```

This returns :

```
Text    Count
Val 1   3
Val 2   1
Val 3   1
Val 4   0
```

The `CROSS APPLY` function calculates `COUNT(*)` for the T2 rows that have a Value equal to `t1.Value` and returns just that count.

Comment: The question doesn't give an example of desired output or clearly describe it.

Comment: Thanks dear friend. I change `Count(*)` to `Count(id)` and it returns `0` for `Val 4` :-?

Comment: @Arian and a simple `OR Year IS NULL` would fix the original query too. Sometimes the solution is a *lot* simpler than one thinks at first. Leszek's answer is *another* simple solution

Answer (score 2):

It is all about order of executing statements, so in your case:

1. `from @Tbl1 t1 left join @Tbl2 t2 on t1.Value = t2.[Value]` Here you got some values with `Val 4` but combined with t2 data
2. `where t2.Year=2011` In this step all rows with `Val 4` are filtered
3. `group by t1.[Text]`
4. `select t1.[Text], count(*)`
5. `order by 1`

In yours second statement you filter t2 on "FROM" stage, so you receive `Val 4` value from t1 but with nulled t2 elements (because "LEFT OUTER JOIN") and next you count *, so every row, and here is row. You should use count(t2.[Value]) instead:

```sql
SELECT t1.[Text], COUNT(t2.[Value])
FROM @Tbl1 t1 
LEFT JOIN @Tbl2 t2 
  ON t1.[Value] = t2.[Value] 
  AND t2.[Year] = 2011
GROUP BY t1.[Text]
ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 1):

when you use any condition "t2.Year=2011" in where it this section

```
select t1.[Text], count(*) as 'Count'
from @Tbl1 t1 left join @Tbl2 t2 on t1.Value = t2.[Value] 
where t2.Year=2011
group by t1.[Text]
order by 1
```

its like use inner join and in your record you haven't any 2011 for value 4

```
select t1.[Text], count(*) as 'Count'
from @Tbl1 t1 inner join @Tbl2 t2 on t1.Value = t2.[Value] 
where t2.Year=2011
group by t1.[Text]
order by 1
```

because ts.year=2011 is not in the return set so it is filter

but when use condition t2.Year=2011 in the left join it is really left join

```
select t1.[Text], count(*)
from @Tbl1 t1 left join @Tbl2 t2 on t1.Value = t2.[Value] and t2.Year=2011
group by t1.[Text]
order by 1
```

and one of  data that basically retrieve is

```
 text     t2.year
 ----------------       
 val 4     null
```

when you use count(*) so it is return 1

```
 text     count
 ----------------       
 val 4     1
```

Comment: This is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. Also you know proper punctuation & capitalization, so please give it.